# How to put a blank line between two images in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I have a Doxygen comment with images:

```
/**
 * @brief some brief comment
 *
 * More text:
 * @image html image1.png
 * @image html image2.png
 */
```

When generating the HTML documentation the two images are directly below each other. I would like to put a blank line between them.

Simply putting in a blank line (see code below) in the comment does not have an effect.

```
/**
 * @brief some brief comment
 *
 * More text:
 * @image html image1.png
 *
 * @image html image2.png
 */
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen docs (link below) states that it supports "HTML Commands" - you can insert html tags directly. Try inserting `<BR>` between images.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html

Comment: This creates a new paragraph with a newline break inside. Works for me, but the spaces this solution creates is much more than a mere newline.